# Results of opencv dnn looks weird when using the tensorflow model(faster rcnn) to detect the object

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

- [Link of the model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)
- [Link of the model zip file](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_oid_2018_01_28.tar.gz)
- OS : win10 64
- opencv: 4.1.2, installed by anaconda
- tensorflow: 1.15, installed by pip

Steps to reproduce

1 : Generate the config file by tf_text_graph_faster_rcnn.py

python tf_text_graph_faster_rcnn.py --input frozen_inference_graph.pb --config pipeline.config --output faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_oid.pbtxt

frozen_inference_graph.pb and pipeline.config are the files after unzip

2 : detect object by the example codes

```
import cv2 as cv

cvNet = cv.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('tensorflow/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_oid.pb', 'tensorflow/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_oid.pbtxt')

img = cv.imread('traffic_jam.jpg')
rows = img.shape[0]
cols = img.shape[1]
cvNet.setInput(cv.dnn.blobFromImage(img, size=(300, 300), swapRB=True, crop=False))
cvOut = cvNet.forward()

for detection in cvOut[0,0,:,:]:
    score = float(detection[2])
    if score > 0.1:
        left = detection[3] * cols
        top = detection[4] * rows
        right = detection[5] * cols
        bottom = detection[6] * rows
        cv.rectangle(img, (int(left), int(top)), (int(right), int(bottom)), (23, 230, 210), thickness=2)

cv.imshow('img', img)
cv.waitKey()
```

The results

1. Input image

[image]

2. Results

[image]

The results detected by tensorflow algorithm on [this page](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API)

[image]

Although there are still a lot of cars cannot detect, but the results are quite different compare with the api of opencv

Edit : Results detected by the ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco, much better results, I guess opencv dnn module do not works well with the model I post?

[image]

Edit2 : Codes of ssd detection

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2 as cv

# Read the graph.
#with tf.gfile.FastGFile('tensorflow/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_oid.pb', 'rb') as f:
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("tensorflow/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Restore session
    sess.graph.as_default()
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

    # Read and preprocess an image.
    img = cv.imread('traffic_jam.jpg')
    rows = img.shape[0]
    cols = img.shape[1]
    inp = cv.resize(img, (300, 300))
    inp = inp[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]  # BGR2RGB

    # Run the model
    out = sess.run([sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0'),
                    sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0'),
                    sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0'),
                    sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')],
                    feed_dict={'image_tensor:0': inp.reshape(1, inp.shape[0], inp.shape[1], 3)})

    # Visualize detected bounding boxes.
    num_detections = int(out[0][0])
    for i in range(num_detections):
        classId = int(out[3][0][i])
        score = float(out[1][0][i])
        bbox = [float(v) for v in out[2][0][i]]
        if score > 0.1:
            x = bbox[1] * cols
            y = bbox[0] * rows
            right = bbox[3] * cols
            bottom = bbox[2] * rows
            cv.rectangle(img, (int(x), int(y)), (int(right), int(bottom)), (125, 255, 51), thickness=2)

cv.imshow('TensorFlow MobileNet-SSD', img)
cv.waitKey()
```

Comment: with the sample network on that website, do you get same results as in they get?

Comment: @MickI I do not know where could I find the original image of the example, but you can see the result of the image detected by ssd mobileNet

Comment: maybe the r-cnn backend isnt implemented correctly/completely in opencv (the other model is a ssd model). I dont know about the tensorflow detection api, is there some kind of "version"? Maybe you can find out the version that is implemented in opencv and the version that is used by your model?

Comment: the other thing: I don't think images are resized to 300x300 when using an r-cnn, but I might be wrong. Isn't r-cnn some kind of sliding-window-approach? Is the tensorflow code for the ssd model giving similar results on your test image?

Comment: @Micka The last image is the result detected by the ssd model(tensorflow code), much better than rcnn which should provide better results.

Comment: can you add the result of that ssd model with opencv code, too?

Comment: @Micka posted, it is same as the example of opencv wiki

Answer (score 0):

```
cvNet.setInput(cv.dnn.blobFromImage(img, size=(300, 300), swapRB=True, crop=False))
```

300x300 is incorrect input size because the `pipeline.config` has the following preprocessing directives:

```
image_resizer {
  keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
    min_dimension: 600
    max_dimension: 1024
  }
}
```

That means you have to keep image ratio. Try to process an origin frame (it has 800x600):

```
cvNet.setInput(cv.dnn.blobFromImage(img, swapRB=True))
```

output with confidence threshold `0.3` and `pipeline.config` modification mentioned [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13237#issuecomment-455592112)

```
    height_stride: 16
    width_stride: 16
```

[image]